# Program which accepts grades and prints grade distribution

Tags: java, statistics, ascii-art, data-visualization

I'm doing the [MOOC Java course](https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part1/week-6/) (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> "distribution"):

> The input of the program is a set of exam scores of a course. Each score is an integer. When -1 is entered, the program stops asking for further input.
>
> After the scores have been read, the program prints the grade distribution and acceptance percentage of the course.
>
> Grade distribution is formed as follows:
>
> - Each exam score is mapped to a grade using the same formula as in exercise 18. If the score is not within the range 0-60 it is not taken into account.
> - The number of grades are printed as stars, e.g. if there are 2 scores that correspond to grade 5, the line 5: ** is printed. If there are no scores that correspond to a particular grade, the printed line is 4:
>
> All the grades besides zeros are accepted, so in the above 7 out of 8 participants were accepted. Acceptance percentage is calculated with the formula 100*accepted/allScores.

The formula in exercise 18 is:

```
<table >
      <tr>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Grade</th> 

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0-29</td>
        <td>Failed</td> 

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30-34</td>
        <td>1</td> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>35-39</td>
        <td>2</td> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>40-44</td>
        <td>3</td> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>45-49</td>
        <td>4</td> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>50-60</td>
        <td>5</td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I wrote code that seems to work fine based on my tests, no compile errors, no run-time errors (except for cases where you enter a string instead of a number or a ridiculously large number).

I tested it using input from the table above, i.e I entered the numbers (0, 29, 30, 34, 35, 39, 40, 44, 45, 49, 50, 60), and there were two stars printed in each grade range, as expected. I also tested it with numbers in between the ranges, and numbers outside of [0, 60]. I found no logical errors.

I found the names I used too repetitive, `GradeDistribution` class, 3 arrays called `gradeRanges`, `gradeDistributionList`, `gradeList`.

Other problems: The logic of calculating `gradeDistribution` seems too nested. Should I have used switch-case? Should I have used static methods instead of a class? Should I have combined the methods `calculateGradeDistribution` and `printGradeDistribution` into one? Am I worrying too much about little things?

This is main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int number = 0;
        System.out.println("Type exam scores, -1 to end");
        do{
            number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if(number != -1){
                grades.add(number);
            }
        }while(number != -1);

        GradeDistribution syrianGradeDistribution = new GradeDistribution();
        syrianGradeDistribution.calculateGradeDistribution(grades);
        syrianGradeDistribution.printGradeDistribution();
        System.out.println(syrianGradeDistribution.acceptancePercentage());
    }
}
```

This is the `GradeDistribution` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GradeDistribution {
    private ArrayList<Integer> gradeRanges = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> gradeDistributionList = new ArrayList<>();

    public GradeDistribution(){
        Collections.addAll(gradeRanges, 0, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 61);
        Collections.addAll(gradeDistributionList, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void calculateGradeDistribution(ArrayList<Integer> gradeList){
        for(int grade: gradeList){
            if(grade < 0 || grade > 60){ //invalid grades
                continue;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < gradeRanges.size() -1 ; i++){
                 if(grade >= gradeRanges.get(i) && grade < gradeRanges.get(i + 1)){
                    gradeDistributionList.set(i, gradeDistributionList.get(i)+ 1);
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printGradeDistribution(){
        for(int i = 0; i < gradeDistributionList.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(i + ": ");
            for(int j = 0; j < gradeDistributionList.get(i); j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public double acceptancePercentage(){
        int allScores = 0;
        for(int number: gradeDistributionList){
            allScores += number;
        }
        int acceptedScores = allScores - gradeDistributionList.get(0);
        double acceptancePercentage = 100.0 * acceptedScores / allScores;
        return acceptancePercentage;
    }
}
```

The code compiles without any errors on Windows 10, Java 11.0.2.

This is a very simple program, but yet, I still have many questions about the choices I made. How can I become confident in my choices and know what's acceptable and what's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any errors in the code. However, I do not like the choice of data structure in `GradeDistribution`. Not only are insertions slow -- taking time linear in the number of ranges -- but it is also unnecessarily involved. Java has a wealth of data structures in the standard library. Choosing the right one can make your code faster and cleaner. I recommend `TreeMap`, which has a `floorEntry` method that makes is easy to find the appropriate range for a given score.

More detailed critique:

- Use constants to hold magic numbers like the min/max scores and ranges.
- Add scores to the data structure one at a time instead of as a list.
- Shorten variables and method names.
- Use name `getAcceptedPercent` to make it clear this method is an accessor.
- Use `Scanner.nextInt` and `Scanner.hasNextInt`.
- Use an infinite loop and break to avoid checking `number != -1` twice.
- Keep track of total and accepted scores as you go.

Here is my implementation, which addresses each issue:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        GradeDistribution grades = new GradeDistribution();

        System.out.println("Type exam scores, -1 to end");
        while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            int number = reader.nextInt();
            if (number == -1) {
                break;
            }
            grades.add(number);
        }

        grades.print();
        System.out.println(grades.getAcceptedPercent());
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GradeDistribution {
    private static final int MIN = 0, MAX = 60;
    private static final int[] RANGE_STARTS = {0, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};

    private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> rangeCount = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
    private int totalScores = 0, acceptedScores = 0;

    public GradeDistribution(){
        for (int s : RANGE_STARTS) {
            rangeCount.put(s, 0);
        }
    }

    public void add(int grade) {
        if (grade < MIN || grade > MAX) {
            return;
        }

        Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e = rangeCount.floorEntry(grade);
        rangeCount.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + 1);

        totalScores++;
        if (e.getKey() > MIN) {
            acceptedScores++;
        }
    }

    public void print(){
        int rangeNum = 1;
        for (int count : rangeCount.tailMap(MIN, false).values()) {
            System.out.printf("%d: ", rangeNum++);
            for (; count > 0; count--) {
                System.out.print('*');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public double getAcceptedPercent(){
        return (100.0 * acceptedScores) / totalScores;
    }
}
```

There is another further improvements you could consider, though I did not implement it here for the sake of brevity. You could use a mutable type for the map values. If, say the map was of type `TreeMap<Integer,WrappedInteger>` for a type `WrappedInteger` that supports an `increment` operation, we could write `e.getValue().increment()` instead of the `put` in the current implementation. This is potentially faster, as it avoids accessing the tree again.